# Array Index Out of Bounds Error in Java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

```
package test1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int traincars;
        int maxweight;
        int count = 0;
        int total = 0;

        maxweight = input.nextInt();
        traincars = input.nextInt();
        int[] trains = new int[traincars];

        for(int i = 0; i < traincars; i++)
        {
            trains[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        if (total < maxweight)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < traincars; i++)
            {
                total = trains[i] + trains[i+1] + trains[i+2] + trains[i+3];
                count++;
            }
        }else
        {
            count = count + 3;
        }
System.out.println("count");
    }
}
```

this is a really simple program but for some reason, the array for the traincars goes out of bounds..

Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you post the error output?

Comment: Uh, what line is getting the error?  And if you can't isolate it some other way, break your trains + trains + trains statement into multiple substatements, so only one array indexing op occurs per line.  (But the cause is pretty obvious -- if i == traincars -1 then i+3 will be traincars+2 and out of the range of the array.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last iteration of

```
        for(int i = 0; i < traincars; i++)
        {
            total = trains[i] + trains[i+1] + trains[i+2] + trains[i+3];
            count++;
        }
```

You try to access `trains[i+1]` and this is bigger than the length of your `trains` array.

To make this `for` loop matter you should just do the following:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < traincars; i++)
        {
            total += trains[i]; //unless of course you need something else...
            count++;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < traincars; i++)
        {
            total = trains[i] + trains[i+1] + trains[i+2] + trains[i+3];
            count++;
        }
```

When `i` equals `traincars-1` you will be accessing elements `i+1`, `i+2`. and `i+3` which are out of bounds of your `trains` array.

If your logic is calling for calculating totals of 4 consecutive elements of the array then your `for` loop should stop earlier:

```
for(int i = 0; i < traincars - 3; i++) {...}
```

Comment: thanks! i caught onto this and managed to fix it already. thanks for your help though.